# jquery file upload dataType script IE issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

I still have troubles using jquery fileupload plugin, only on IE.

The javascript is something like this:

```
$('input#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/upload_attachment.js',
    dataType: 'script',
 ................
 ................

$('input#realupload').bind('change', function(e){
   $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {
    dataType: 'script',
    files: e.target.files || [{name: this.value}],
    fileInput: $(this)
 }); 
 e.preventDefault();       
});
```

This is the request header:

```
 Key    Value
 Request    POST /holdings/183400184/upload_attachment HTTP/1.1
 Accept text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
 Referer    http://192.168.1.209:3000/holdings/183400184
 Accept-Language    en-NZ
 User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
 Content-Type   multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dc1d02610132
 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
 Host   192.168.1.209:3000
 Content-Length 196
 Connection Keep-Alive
 Cache-Control  no-cache
 Cookie xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I specify the dataType to be: 'script' and I return from server:

```
 Key    Value
 Response   HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
 Content-Type   text/javascript; charset=utf-8
 Cache-Control  max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
 X-Ua-Compatible    IE=Edge
 X-Runtime  4.625297
 Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2011-10-30)
 Date   Wed, 25 Jan 2012 02:52:48 GMT
 Content-Length 345
 Connection Keep-Alive
 Set-Cookie ******************
```

And the response body is:

```
var li = '<li>';
li += '<img alt="Paperclip" src="/images/paperclip.png?1323904510" /> ';
li += '<a href="/XXXXX/183400184/download_attachment/980191034">test.txt</a> <img alt="Cross_16x16" data_url="/XXXXX/183400184/destroy_attachment/980191034" src="/images/cross_16x16.png?1327452770" />';
li += '</li>';
$('ul#attachments').append(li);
```

On chrome, firefox, etc... all good.

On IE it ask me if I want to open or save the update_attachment.js  ????

The other ajax calls work fine, it interprets the javascript response properly, only using fileupload no....

edit:

IE is not passing in the request header:

```
  X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answers my question

> forceIframeTransport
>
> Set this option to true to force iframe transport uploads, even if the
>   browser is capable of XHR file uploads. This can be useful for
>   cross-site file uploads, if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
>   cannot be set for the server-side upload handler which is required for
>   cross-site XHR file uploads.

```
Type: boolean
Default: false
```

IE is not doing a XHR request...